# How to Bind Exclude more than one property from a model with linq to sql asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, object

I have a form with a select box on it.

The linq entity has a selectList as a public property on it.

I'm currently excluding it from the entity like this

```
[Bind(Exclude = "taskDeadlineTime")]
```

I now want to add a second drop down, and I'm getting this error when I try to UpdateModel()

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Is it right that I should be adding this new property to the bind exclude list?

If so how do I add more than one property to the list?

Comment: duplicate? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object/

Comment: I don't think so, I haven't really changed the controller. Also it works fine if I remove the instance of the select list from the view. If the bind exclude works fine, why can't I just extend it out for multiple properties? Do I just need to know the syntax for doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exclude takes a comma separated list of property names, just add another.

Complete Docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work, 

[Bind(Exclude = "taskDeadlineTime", "taskStartTime")]

error named attribute argument expected, please can you show me the exact syntax, I have tried quite a few?

Comment: [Bind(Exclude = "Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, ...")]

Comment: Yep, thats it, I tried so many different things, grouping strings inside a single literal caught me out. The correct was [Bind(Exclude = "taskDeadlineTime,taskStartTime")]