# ASP.NET MVC2 Error: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

**Edit: This is fixed -- See Solution below**

**Solution**: First I incorrectly had my  node defined in /shared/web.config instead of the web.config in the root of the WebUI project. I also had not correctly defined my connection string within web.config. I have pasted the proper web.config sections below:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor"/>
  <!--more sectiongroup and sections redacted for brevity -->
  </configSections>
  <castle>
      <components>
          <component id="ProdsRepository" service="DomainModel.Abstract.IProductsRepository, DomainModel" type="DomainModel.Concrete.SqlProductsRepository, DomainModel">
              <parameters>
                  <connectionString>Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=SportsStore; Integrated Security=SSPI</connectionString>
              </parameters>
          </component>
      </components>
  </castle>
```

I also had to adjust the method body of WindsorControllerFactory.cs (IoC Container) to return null for invalid requests like so:

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    if (controllerType == null)
        return null;
    else
    return (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
}
```

**End of Solution**

I'm following the book Pro ASP.NET MVC2 by Sanderson. I've implemented the IoC container and gotten the web.config straightened out. When I attempt to run my application I get the error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

After some searching I found this exact issue on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object). The solution is to create the constructor with no parameters but I'm having an issue doing this. I've pasted the code from ProductsController.cs below

```
namespace WebUI.Controllers
    {
        public class ProductsController : Controller
           {
               private IProductsRepository productsRepository;
               public ProductsController(IProductsRepository productsRepository)
               {
                   this.productsRepository = productsRepository;
               }

        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View(productsRepository.Products.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Above the public ProductsController that has parameters I tried doing:

```
public ProductsRepository() : this(new productsRepository())
{
}
```

I'm unclear about exactly what needs to go after the "new". IProductsRepository doesn't seem to work and neither does what I have written. I have pasted the stack trace below:

```
Stack Trace: 


[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +230
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'WebUI.Controllers.ProductsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +190
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +118
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +46
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +63
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +13
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8682818
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Posting WindsorControllerFactory.cs code:

```
namespace WebUI
{
    public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        WindsorContainer container;

        // The contructor:
        // 1. Sets up a new IoC container
        // 2. Registers all components specified in web.config
        // 3. Registers all controller types as components
        public WindsorControllerFactory()
        {
            // Instantiate a container, taking config from web.config
            container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));

            // Also register all the controller types as transient
            var controllerTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                  where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                                  select t;
            foreach (Type t in controllerTypes)
                container.AddComponentLifeStyle(t.FullName, t, Castle.Core.LifestyleType.Transient);
        }

        // Constructs the controller instance needed to service each request
        protected override IController  GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
        }

    }
}
```

Edit2: Pertinent Web.config nodes:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="castle"
             type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,
                 Castle.Windsor" />
  </configSections>
  <castle>
    <components>
      <component id="ProdsRepository"
                 service="DomainModel.Abstract.IproductsRepository, DomainModel"
                 type="DomainModel.Concrete.SqlProductsRepository, DomainModel"></component>
      <parameters>
      </parameters>
    </components>
  </castle>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: No parameterless constructor defined for this object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object)

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure a custom controller factory in order to wire up your DI framework inside `Application_Start` method in global.asax. So for example if you are using Unity as DI framework you could:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
    typeof(UnityControllerFactory)
);
```

Check out [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/05/07/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-app-using-unity-2-0.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I have this entry already in my Global.asax file, for using Castle Windsor.

ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory());

Comment: @Caley Woods, could you show your code registering the controllers and their dependencies with castle windsor?

Comment: I noticed I don't have a connectionString defined in my components section, any idea how to implement that?
<connectionString>
</connectionString> according to the book but I'm not positive what goes between there.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of setter based injection

```
    public class ProductsController : Controller 

{   
    private IProductsRepository productsRepository; 

    public ProductsController()
    {

    } 
    public ViewResult List() 
    {
        return View(productsRepository.Products.ToList());
    }

    public IProductsRepository MyRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return productsRepository;
        }

        set
        {
            productsRepository = value;
        }
    }
}
```

here , you need to manually set the MyRepository.

but best would be , if you register your repository to a container and beliving that you are using Unity framework , so you can do it by IUnityContainer.RegisterType() method