# unity dependency Injection and redirect to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection

i use Unity DI in project, but when redirect from one action to another get this error:
No parameterless constructor defined for this object. in FirstController _service property is initialized correct, and when call SecondController directly _service property is initialized correct, but when use RedirctToAction method from FirstController to redirect to SecondController get this Error:No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
my sample code is:

```
public interface IService
{
    string Get();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Data";
    }
}
public class FirstController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public FirstController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Second"); -----> this line
    }
}

public class SecondController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public SecondController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

DI Code:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();

        System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new DependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IService, Service>();

        return container;
    }
}

public class DependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;

    public DependencyResolver(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        _unityContainer = unityContainer;

    }
    public object GetService(System.Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            var service = _unityContainer.Resolve(serviceType);

            return service;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(System.Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _unityContainer.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }
}
```

Application_Start Initialise:

```
Bootstrapper.Initialise();
```

Comment: Show us how you configured Unity.

Comment: What is ViewModel for Index action in SecondController? Maybe it is same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object?