# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. MVC, Angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have looked at quite a few articles here, but none of them seem to be suitable for my case. If it helps or pertains to the issue, I am using ninjectMVC for dependency injection.

I have an Angular $http as such:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Lookup/GetChangeOptions/'
}).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var test = data;
    //$scope.changeOptions = data;
}).error(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

Which calls my controller:

```
public class LookupController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILookupService _lookupService;

    public LookupController(ILookupService lookupService)
    {
        _lookupService = lookupService;
    }

    public JsonResult GetOtherIssues()
    {
        var otherIssues = _lookupService.GetOtherIssues();

        return Json(otherIssues);
    }

    public JsonResult GetChangeOptions()
    {
        var changeOptions = _lookupService.GetChangeOptions();

        return Json(changeOptions);
    }
}
```

The call is giving me the error:

"System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

I am not sure what is causing the issue.. I have used similar structures in the past without any problems. Please let me know if I need to put the code of my service, but when I debug the call.. my break point in the controller is not even hit.

Comment: is your ioc container properly registered?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object?rq=1

Comment: That was it, such a stupid mistake. Thanks a lot boss. 
Because of a previous issue, i had excluded the IOC initialization from the project and forgot to add it back again.

Could you post this in a new post, so I can mark it as the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your IoC container is still resolving.