# No parameterless constructor defined for this object for home controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
>          System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>          System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
>          System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +256
>          System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127
>          System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +92
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Web.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +256
>          System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +81
>          Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IControllerFactory_CreateController.InvokeMethodOnTarget() +155
>          Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +116
>          Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context) +71
>          Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +604
>          Castle.Proxies.IControllerFactoryProxy.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +193
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +270
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +86
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12639055
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18447

Comment: You don't have empty constructor for your HomeController and it should be present.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: No parameterless constructor defined for this object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following parameterless constructor to your controller:

```
public HomeController()
{
  //...
}
```

Internally, the MVC engine (`DefaultControllerActivator`) is looking for such a constructor in order to instantiate your controller.