# MVC 6 - No Parameterless Constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an MVC 6 project (MVC Movies) which has SQL tables such as AspNetUsers.

I want to be able to display a list of Users who are on the AspNetUsers table so for that I have a Model 'AspNetUsers':

```
public class AspNetUsers
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I also then have another class 'AspNetUserInfo' which holds a List of AspNetUsers:

```
public class AspNetUserInfo
{
    public List<AspNetUsers> MyUserList { get; set; }
}
```

To show this list I then need a Controller with Views, and this is where my issue Starts: 
Everytime I try to create Views I am met with this:

[image]

I can create a Controller (without views) and I have done:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        AspNetUserInfo userInfo = new Models.AspNetUserInfo();
        List<AspNetUsers> aspUsers = userInfo.MyUserList.ToList();
        return View(aspUsers);
    }
```

I cannot create a Controller with views nor can I create views for this controller without seeing the error above.
I think that I need to add a Parameterless Constructor in my ApplicationDbContext but I am unsure how to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: public AspNetUsers()(}?

Comment: ActionInvoker is the component that invokes the action in the controller.  I think this might mean your controller doesn't have an empty constructor?

Comment: Hi James please refer the below stackoverflow post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object

Comment: @Chandruvelan Thanks I'll take a look and hopefully understand it

Comment: Are you using `dependecy injection` in your project ?

Comment: It complains about the dbcontext, can you show the constructor(s) for your controller?

Comment: @SunilKumar I think that my AspNetUserInfo class relies on AspNetUser class to create the list if that is what you mean?

Comment: Answer is probably no empty constructor on your controller but also if you have an AspNetUsers table I assume you are using Identity Framework so why are you creating these classes instead of using framework?

Comment: refer this link : http://www.nicholasbarger.com/posts/fun-and-struggles-with-mvc---no-parameterless-constructor-defined