# Binding a wrapper class on Ajax POST

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC wrapper class that wraps a List containing ViewModels:

```
public class ScheduleContainerViewModel
{
    public List<SchedulingViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ScheduleContainerViewModel(List<SchedulingViewModel> items)
    {
        Items = items;
}
```

`SchedulingViewModel` contains a `Schedule` object and a `Users` object.

`ScheduleContainerViewModel` is eventually passed to a `PartialView`. 
This `PartialView` is called via Ajax to populate a div in a `View`. The model for the `PartialView` is `ScheduleContainerViewModel` and the model for the `View` is a `Job`.

The Ajax GET works great. When I try to `POST` it, however, the Controller is never called and I get a 500 server error. Here's some of the XHR data being `POST`ed:
[image]

It seems to me that List `Items` is being passed, containing `SchedulingViewModel`s and their associated `Schedules`, but maybe not?

There are three relevant methods in the Controller. Here are their signatures:

```
public ActionResult ScheduleJob(int? id)
public ActionResult Table(int? id)
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Table(ScheduleContainerViewModel cvm)
```

`ScheduleJob` loads the initial View, which calls `[HttpGet] Table` to load the PartialView. Finally, `[HttpPost] Table` is the one being `POST`ed to. Why can't the model binder see the data being passed to it in the XHR?

My only guess it that it's because the model used by the `View` called by `ScheduleJob` is different than the one being `POST`ed to `[HttpPost] Table`.

Comment: _I get a 500 server error_ What is this error? You should be able to hit the `Response` tab in the above screenshot to view it or simply debug the post in Visual Studio. _My only guess it that it's because the model used by the View called by ScheduleJob is different than the one being POSTed to_ - Doesn't matter.

Comment: It's an HTML error page with the error `System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`, for the `SchedulingViewModel`. Would ASP know how to populate a `SchedulingViewModel` with no constructor just given the XHR data above?

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object) it appears to be the problem you are having. on your `ScheduleContainerViewModel` you need a parameterless constructor. i.e. `public ScheduleContainerViewModel() { }`

Comment: I'll answer my own question to say: yes, it can. Thank you!