# ASP.NET No parameterless constructor found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, controller, webapi

When I try running my project using visual Studio the home page is not getting loaded.
I getting an error like `No parameterless constructor found`

Below the entire error

> Server Error in '/' Application. No parameterless constructor defined
> for this object. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
> the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
> trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
> the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
> constructor defined for this object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
> object.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
> Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
> RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
> skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +122
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
> Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
> +239    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +85    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
> requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
> controller of type 'App1.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that
> the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
> requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
> requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
> requestContext, String controllerName) +102
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
> httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
> +188    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
> AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
> context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +444    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
> step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

HomeController

```
public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env) 
{ 
    storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("", ""); 
    cloudStorage = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true); 
    cloudBlob = cloudStorage.CreateCloudBlobClient(); 
    cloudblobcontainer = cloudBlob.GetContainerReference("container name"); 
    this.hostingEnv = env; 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object is this similar problem?

Comment: Can you show the HomeController code

Comment: public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("", "");
            cloudStorage = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
            cloudBlob = cloudStorage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            cloudblobcontainer = cloudBlob.GetContainerReference("container name");
            this.hostingEnv = env;
        }